# Modal of each row in table won't dismiss

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

i have a page where i display products into table, each row have a button to show a modal that displays the image of the product, modal shows up fine but won't dismiss when clicking outside it or even when pressing close button!(in the code above there is no close button, i know)

```
<tbody>
@foreach($table_data as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ getCategoryType($product->taggable_type) }}</td>
    <td>{{ ($product->discount*100)."%" }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->is_decorated ? 'Complex' : 'Simple' }}</td>
    <td class="align-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-b-10 m-l-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$loop->index}}">Image</button>
        <div id="myModal{{$loop->index}}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel{{$loop->index}}" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="{{asset('Images/products/'.$product->id.".jpg")}}" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-b-10 m-l-5">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-b-10 m-l-5">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This isn't a Laravel question it is a jQuery (JavaScript) question. Looking at what you've posted I can't even see anywhere that would suggest closing / hiding the modal.

Comment: the modal should be dismissed when clicking outside its boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dismiss modal button, e.g.:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-gray btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
```

Comment: I've said that even with the close button it won't dismiss!!. with the above code it should be dismissed when clicking outside the modal.

Comment: Do you have a script somewhere that is changing modal options? ```$('#id').modal({ backdrop: 'true', keyboard: false, show: false });```

Comment: hmmm, no! should i write this line for each modal with #id = to the id of the button ?!

Comment: could you explain to me how to code this kind of script !!

Comment: Try simplifying the problem to see if you can isolate the issue. Get rid of the foreach loop and verify that a modal will close for a single instance. If not, try removing all other code/scripts until you get a working example. Once you have  a working example, start slowly adding the original code back in until it breaks. This will isolate the issue for you.

Comment: bootstrap modal does not work individually or in a loop like my case, in my project .. I think bcuz of I'm using a template based in bs4. any way I've used jquery-confirm.js and it worked like a charm